# A day/Month vs In a day/ month

Tags: prepositions

> How many times do you brush a day?

Vs

> How many times do you brush **in** a day?

And

> How much do you earn a month?

Vs

> How much do you earn **in** a month?

Answer (score -1):

Great question! “Times a month” would refer to an indefinite number of months, as in, “I earn $1000 a month.” “Times in a month” refers to one specific month. “Times in a month” is rare though because “a” is an indefinite article; “times in one month” would be more natural, as in, “Last year I earned $1000 in one month.” In this case, I’m referring to a specific month (with the implication that I didn’t earn that amount in  the other months). “Times in a month” would be reserved for special cases in which you’re referring to an unspecific specific month, as in, “How much did you earn in a month?” where you’re referring to a single month, but not one in particular.